# three.js - using more than one samplercube

Tags: opengl-es, three.js

i am writng a shader that needs to use one sampler cube for reflection and another for refraction. water is intended to reflect form a skybox, but refract using a container for the water. i create a uniform in the fragment shader for each sampler cube:

uniform samplerCube reflectMap;
uniform samplerCube refractMap;

i create 2 texture cubes, tRefract and tReflect, using THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube

i associate the uniforms to the custom shader, setting their values:

```
  refractMap: {type: 't', value: tRefract}
  reflectMap: {type: 't', value: tReflect}
```

in the fragment shader i sample the textures and mix the colors:

```
vec4 reflectCubeColor = textureCube(reflectMap, vec3(-vReflect.x, vReflect.yz));
vec4 refractCubeColor = textureCube(refractMap, vec3(-vRefract.x, vRefract.yz));
vec3 c = mix(gl_FragColor.xyz, reflectCubeColor.xyz, reflectivity);
gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(refractCubeColor.xyz, c, opacity), 1.0);
```

(vReflect and vRefract have been computed in the vertex shader)

what happens, however, is only the texture associated to the reflection is used. it appears on the skybox, it is reflected in the water and refracted in the water.

thinking maybe this was a question of not switching texture units as one might do in "regular" opengl, i dug around in the three.js code to see if there was a way to specify the texture unit. it appears in the built-in normal shader that something like this might doing just that:

```
  refractMap: {type: 't', value: 6, texture: tRefract}
  reflectMap: {type: 't', value: 7, texture: tReflect}
```

where value is specifying the texture unit. i didn't see any api, however, for saying which unit should be the active unit. it doesn't seem to matter the order in which the textures are loaded or associated to uniforms, and changing the values associated as above seems to have no effect.

so can i make use of more than one samplerCube in my fragment shader ?

Comment: What version of the library are you using? Upgrade to r.66 and use this pattern: `refractMap: { type: 't', value: tRefract }`

Comment: it's version r66. note as shown above that that is what i tried first.

Comment: Read my suggestion carefully.

Comment: my apologies. what i typed initially was incorrect. the first thing i tried was:

  refractMap: {type: 't', value: tRefract}
  reflectMap: {type: 't', value: tReflect}

the second thing i tried was:

  refractMap: {type: 't', value: 6, texture: tRefract}
  reflectMap: {type: 't', value: 7, texture: tReflect}

a bad case of not writing what i thought i was writing. sorry.

Comment: so i edited the original question to correct my mistake.

Comment: I hacked http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_shaders_fresnel.html to take two `samplerCube`s without a problem.

Comment: so that the bubbles could reflect using one and refract using the other ?

Comment: Yes. See if you can do the same.

Comment: yes, altering that example does work. and i'm not doing anything different with the textures than i was in my own example, so something else must be causing the problem. thanks for the help!